# How to round down an address in C?

Tags: c, pointers

Say I had a char* ptr with address of 0x7fffaf6aa87f, How can I round that down to a multiple of 8 so that it would be 0x7fffaf6aa878?

or if it was 0x7fffaf6aa875, it would get rounded down to 0x7fffaf6aa870.

Comment: Cast to `unsigned long`, do a bitwise AND, and cast back to a pointer.

Comment: `uintptr_t` is a better type to cast to.

Comment: It sounds like you are worried about alignment issues.   Arithmetic rounding and memory alignment issues are related, but I suspect there is a better way to solve your actual problem than rounding the pointer value.

Comment: Why do you think this is a reasonable thing to do? <- your answer to this question will make the answer to ^that question more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## &~7

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void) {
    uintptr_t x = 0x7fffaf6aa87f;
    uintptr_t y = x&~7;
    
    printf("%p\n", y);
    
    x = 0x7fffaf6aa875;
    y = x&~7;
    printf("%p\n", y);
    
    return 0;
}
```

## Result:

```
Success #stdin #stdout 0s 5368KB
0x7fffaf6aa878
0x7fffaf6aa870
```

Comment: `~ (uintptr_t) 7` should be used in preference to `~7`. `y` does not have the correct type to print with `%p`.